# respondsToSelector not working in Collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm making Table view in Collection view cell for collection view slide to another page and show information on table view.

it work for show but not work when you select table view cell

I'm create method **respondsToSelector** in didSelectRowAtIndexPath of table view like this

```
NSDictionary *data;

if ([currentTab isEqualToString:@"active"]) {
    data = (NSDictionary *) [self.ActiveList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if ([currentTab isEqualToString:@"used"]) {
    data = (NSDictionary *) [self.UsedList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableCell:Click:)]) {
    NSLog(@"respondsToSelector");
    [self.delegate tableCell:self Click:data[@"code"]];
}
```

in **.h** create this

> @protocol TableCellDelegate;
>
> @interface TableFieldCell : UICollectionViewCell
>
> @property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
>
> @protocol tableFieldCellDelegate
>
> @optional
>   - (void)tableCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell Click:(NSString *)key;
>
> @end

How to make it work??????

Comment: Is `self.delegate` nil? Also, it should be `click:` starting with a lowercase according to guidelines. We tend also to write `@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TableCellDelgate > delegate;` to receive a warning if the instance that is set as delegate implements correctly the methods or not.  And the delegate should also be `@protocol TableFieldCellDelegate < NSObject >` (with uppercase, adding also the NSObject stuff.

Comment: Actually, it is fairly confusing. You create a method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath of table view. But  [self.delegate tableCell:self Click:data[@"code"]]; Here self is a tableView ? or a tableViewCell? Why do you call a delegate of tableviewcell as a  delegate of tableView?

Comment: @E.Coms I'm delegate in TableView.

Comment: @Larme **self.delegate** is nil because i don't delegate of Table view in viewController.m.

Comment: And who is supposed to be the set as delegate? So you need to do `cell.delegate = something`?

Comment: @Larme i delegate 'cell.delegate = self' in viewController.

Comment: @I'mNaPat You don't have to name all your delegates `delegate`. This is extremely confusing and error prone. If you have a delegate for your cell tap, maybe call it `clickDelegate` or whatever suits it the best.